# How to network two Windows 11 computers to see all drives and be able to transfer files over the network

Tags: networking, windows-11

With Windows 7 I was able to easily share a drive and view it from another computer at home on my home network. Since Windows 10 I have never successfully found a way to do that. Creating ad hoc networks is gone away. is there any way to do this without third party software?

Comment: What's the problem with connecting the two computers via the router? You may need to enable SMB1 on Windows 10 in "Turn Windows features on or
off".

Comment: All Windows 11 is no problem - browsing works fine. Including earlier operating systems may require you to Map Folders.   I now have a batch file on my desktop to connect folders because that method is (a) universal and (b) simple.

Comment: @harrymc Why the need enable an obsolete and deprecated protocol for network sharing between two Windows 11? Please explain your logic here.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: In case this is used by Windows 7. If it doesn't help, it should of course be undone.

Comment: @harrymc The author merely stated that they could do it easily in Windows 7 and no since Windows 10, it doesn't mean they're still using Windows 7 and they shouldn't.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: Perhaps Windows 7 to Windows 7, who knows.

Comment: @harrymc No, just read the question.

Answer (score 1):

File-sharing functionality (SMB) is still built-in in Windows 11, just as it has been since Windows 95.

About the only thing that Windows 7 "Homegroups" added on top of that was automatic authentication at computer level – without Homegroups you need to supply a username and password for the machine you're accessing, and a blank password is *not* allowed for network logins (though it's possible to relax that requirement via Group Policy).

The instructions for enabling file sharing in Windows 10/11 are available at Microsoft Support website:

- [File sharing over a network in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-sharing-over-a-network-in-windows-b58704b2-f53a-4b82-7bc1-80f9994725bf)

In short:

1. Make sure both computers think they're in a "Private" network (in Windows 11 this is available via "Settings > Network"). This setting relaxes the firewall restrictions, allowing inbound connections from other computers in the same network.

   - [image]
2. Share the disk or folder via SMB. There are a few ways to create a SMB share:

   - If you have "Simple file sharing" enabled (default), right-click the folder you want to share, choose 'Give access to' > 'Specific people', then select a local account or `Everyone` (or nothing, if you only want your own account to have access). Windows will automatically set up a SMB share and set the appropriate file permissions.

     (Folders that are under C:\Users will not be shared individually – instead, Windows will create one common `\\compname\Users` share that lets you browse to the folder. When sharing a folder that's elsewhere, Windows will create a share just for that folder.)
   - You can right-click the disk or folder you want to share, then go to 'Properties' > 'Sharing' and click 'Advanced Sharing'. Enabling 'Share this folder' will create a SMB share that's accessible at `\\computername\sharename`. You'll need to manually set both share-level *and* file-level permissions to grant other users access.
   - In all versions from Windows 2000 you can open the `fsmgmt.msc` app to manage the list of shared folders directly. As above, you'll need to manually grant both file-level access to other users as well as share-level permissions.
3. If the 'server' computer does not show up on the 'client's Network window, manually enter `\\computername` or `\\comp\sharename` as the location. (Failing that, use the computer's LAN IPv4 address.)

(No, you really don't need to enable SMB1. That's only for "version 1" of SMB – it doesn't control SMB availability in general, and you'll generally have better results with SMBv3 anyway.)

Comment: As usual, I followed all the directions and shared a couple drives giving specific permissions to myself and EVERYONE, yet when I clicked on the remote computer in NETWORK, although it shows up in the network list, it could not be found!

Comment: So I go to computer number 1 that could not be found from my laptop, having done the same advanced share on the laptop and when I browse NETWORK from Computer 1, I am asked for the Username and Password for the laptop. I never use a password on my laptop, I have always used a PIN. I was able to change the password on the laptop while using Computer 1 in the Credentials Manager. I still cannot login and browse the shared drives.